# Using process instead of thread with zeromq

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq

I'm reading this code http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:mtserver
But when I've tried to replace `threading.Thread` by `multiprocessing.Process` I got the error

> > Assertion failed: ok (mailbox.cpp:84)

Code is

```
import time
import threading
import zmq

def worker_routine(worker_url, context=None):
    """Worker routine"""
    context = context or zmq.Context.instance()
    # Socket to talk to dispatcher
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)

    socket.connect(worker_url)

    while True:

        string  = socket.recv()

        print("Received request: [ %s ]" % (string))

        # do some 'work'
        time.sleep(1)

        #send reply back to client
        socket.send(b"World")

def main():
    """Server routine"""

    url_worker = "inproc://workers"
    url_client = "tcp://*:5555"

    # Prepare our context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context.instance()

    # Socket to talk to clients
    clients = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    clients.bind(url_client)

    # Socket to talk to workers
    workers = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    workers.bind(url_worker)

    # Launch pool of worker threads
    for i in range(5):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_routine, args=(url_worker,))
        process.start()

    zmq.device(zmq.QUEUE, clients, workers)

    # We never get here but clean up anyhow
    clients.close()
    workers.close()
    context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: _"zmq_inproc - ØMQ local in-process (inter-thread) communication transport"_ - one wouldn't expect an in-process scheme to work cross-process.

Comment: So in order to take advantage of multicore CPU i have to start 4 process manually ? There are no other ways ?

Comment: @nam Your change from multi-thread-ed architecture into multi-process scenario is possible, however **you have to adapt also the proper ZMQ-transport means** ( from *inproc://* class, which is feasible for threaded ( in-process ) architecture -> to another transport class, which remains feasible also for inter-process communications, be it *tcp://* et al ). This has nothing to do with CPU cores and/or methods of process-control ( how a process was started ) et al. ZeroMQ is a very powerfull framework to support you and your plans. **Just keep the ZeroMQ design rules.**

Comment: I don't know enough about `zeromq` to provide an answer, but [here](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/multiprocess/multiprocess.html) is a working `multiprocess` example.

Comment: @PaulRooney: I've read the link but the client send messages to 4 servers in sequence. What i'm trying to do is to make the call in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitations of each transport is detailed in the [API](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-bind).

`inproc` is for intra-process communication (i.e. threads). You should try `ipc` which support inter-process communication or even just `tcp`.

Comment: note that `ipc` is not available on windows, but `tcp` is apparently as fast locally anyway